# Android Studio flagging error in SQLite pragma command, <pragma value> expected, got 'ON'

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I think this is a new error since switching to Android Studio 3.0. I am receiving a lint syntax error:

> `<pragma value> expected, got 'ON'`

I get this error only on the first of the following two methods:

```
private static void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}

private static void setForeignKeyConstraintsDisabled(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;");
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of editor text with underlined error]

I only found one [suggested fix on the internet as of writing](https://www.androidpit.de/forum/758796/android-studio-3-0-fehlermeldung-pragma-value-expected-got-on#3098173). It is in german and says that I shouldn't be using constant strings for pragma but should use a string parameter.

```
String query = String.format ("PRAGMA foreign_keys = %s","ON"); 
db.execSQL(query);
```

But I suspect if this removes the error, it only does so by making the code too complicated for the lint rule to detect.

Why would *ON* throw an error and not *OFF*? Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: My guess is that this is a bug in the Lint rules. You might try [alternative syntax](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) (lowercase `no`, 0, parentheses instead of `=`, etc.) to see if you can get something that is simple and gets past Lint.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks, using the signed number syntax got around the bug

Comment: Despite the comment on your currently-deleted answer, it is perfectly reasonable for you to answer your own question. In particular, for this case, I would have suggested that you write the answer, since you have the working code. I voted to undelete your answer, and I recommend that you restore it.

Comment: done! thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 6):

Using the signed integer [alternative syntax](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) worked.

```
private static void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=1;");
    }
}

private static void setForeignKeyConstraintsDisabled(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=0;");
    }
}
```

Interestingly, using the alternative syntax of yes/no flagged an error on *no* but not *yes*. I agree with @CommonsWare that this seems to be a lint bug.

Comment: don't mind me saying but you should let the @CommonsWare to post it as an answer,IMHO you should have informed him and request him to post it as an answer , but it;s just my opinion (will remove the comment soon , kindly ignore if you don't like it)

Comment: FWIW, I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68755451). `ON`, `on`, and `no` are flagged as invalid, and those latter two are clearly documented as being correct.