# <pragma value> expected, got '?'

Tags: android, sqlite, pragma

Android Studio 3.1

**purpose:** update version number of sqlite database

**error**

> expected, got '?'

the code caused error was

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = ?", new Object[]{questionDbVersion});
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code
> 1): , while compiling: PRAGMA user_version = ?
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)

but in the Sql environment, the sql sentence worked well

```
PRAGMA user_version =1
PRAGMA user_version
PRAGMA user_version =2
```

What should I do?

============
I found a solution

```
db.setVersion(questionDbVersion);
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL grammar as understood by sqlite, [PRAGMA value cannot be a variable](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#syntax), and `?` denotes a variable.

The first error is from Android Studio static analyzer. There have been false positives (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057487/android-studio-flagging-error-in-sqlite-pragma-command-pragma-value-expected)) especially with version 3.0.x but this one is valid error.

The second error is a runtime error for the same.

Use a hardcoded string or `String.format()` formatting for `PRAGMA`s, or as you've found out, for this particular pragma you can use `setVersion()`.